# Plugin upload error on wordpress hosted on AWS linux 2 (EC2 instance) connected with AWS RDS database

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to upload plugin and theme on EC2 instance running on AWS Linux 2 connected with AWS RDB instance (MySQL). I exactly followed these steps presented by AWS.
Creating a MySQL Database with RDS: Configure the RDS database to allow access to specific entities.
Creating an EC2 Instance: Create an EC2 instance to run your WordPress site.
Configuring Your RDS Database: Configure the RDS database to allow access to specific entities.
Configuring WordPress on EC2: Install the WordPress application and dependencies on the EC2 instance.
Reference: [AWS LINK FOR TUTORIAL](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-wordpress-with-amazon-rds/)

However, I am not able to upload plugin or theme, it shows this error:

[image: WordPress error upon upload]

I tried to fix this error using various recommendation, but unable to fix it. The file size in media library is only 2 Mb.
[image: wp admin panel]

1.[wpbeginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-link-you-followed-has-expired-error-in-wordpress/)

I am unable to find .htaccess or php.ini file on wordpress as recommended by wpbeginner.

2.[wpkube](https://www.wpkube.com/how-to-fix-the-link-you-followed-has-expired-error-in-wordpress/)

I tried to create new files (.htaccess and php.ini) recommended here and uploaded at this directory: /var/www/html
This doesn't help to increase Maximum upload file size.

Could someone please help to resolve this issue?

Comment: The .htaccess file mentioned in your provided documentation should be found on same directory level, where you edited the wp-config.php file. If you are not able to see this file, try to do a "ls -la /var/www/html", if this location is the one, where your wp-config.php is stored. The configuration for php can be also set using the configuration files within /etc/php....

Answer (score 1):

you can edit the file in amazon linux -

```
vim /etc/php.ini
```

for upload max size to 100M
after you must restart apache and php
so

```
# sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

then you can check your phpinfo

Answer (score 0):

first step open the php.ini file
sudo vim /etc/php.ini
edit to : max file size - 100M
and
post max size to 100M
save and exit
then
restart httpd and php-fpm
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
sudo systemctl restart httpd

now check for phpinfo output

Comment: This have already been answered. By you.